# Unity Photon can check current player count?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

Now I test my demo game is used the free version that is only 20 ccu. I would like to ask how can I check how many players connect my photon server now. I want to do some waiting function if photon server has 20 players connected.
How can I check? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the count of currently online users connected to the lobby with the `OnLobbyStatisticsUpdate()` callback. Your class must derive from `Photon.PunBehaviour`.

```
public override void OnLobbyStatisticsUpdate()
    {
        string countPlayersOnline;
        countPlayersOnline = PhotonNetwork.countOfPlayers.ToString() + " Players Online";
    }
```

Notice that this update comes with a correct value every 10 seconds (more or less depending on server load).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your answer is very useful. I want to ask a question.  I use the free version(20 ccu). 20 people joined the photon server.  I also join the server. Do you know OnLobbyStatisticsUpdate function will be called and PhotonNetwork.countOfPlayers will change 21?

Comment: Photon lets you go beyond your CCU for a limited time period. After that login will be just rejected. Count will be 20.

Comment: I just find a function "OnPhotonMaxCccuReached". Do you know this function will call if player reach 20?

Comment: If a client can not connect, rejected by the ccu limit you can catch the rejection with `public override void OnPhotonMaxCccuReached()` to put him in a pueue or something.